# How to generate all possible sample paths in Julia from vectors of unequal length

Tags: julia, cartesian-product, julia-jump

I have 5 vectors t1,...,t5, of respective unequal lengths n1, .. ,n5. How can I generate an (n1*...*n5)x(5) matrix in Julia, which would be:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you may be looking for is `Iterators.product` though it does not generate exactly what you request

```
julia> n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;

julia> a = Iterators.product(1:n1, 1:n2, 1:n3, 1:n4, 1:n5)
Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{NTuple{5,UnitRange{Int64}}}((1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5, 1:6))

julia> first(a)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

julia> reduce(vcat, a)
600-element Array{NTuple{5,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
 (2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
 (1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
 (2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
....
```

It doesn't create the Matrix you requested, but most of the time you'll generate a Matrix like that to use it for something else. In this case this is better, as it avoids allocating a temporary Matrix.

@BogumiłKamiński wrote in a comment below that you can get a Matrix (not ordered exactly like the one in your example though) from the object by

```
julia> reduce(vcat, reduce.(hcat,  a))
720×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1  1  1
 2  1  1  1  1
 1  2  1  1  1
...
```

which is maybe not the first thing one would think about, but gets the job done nicely.

Comment: Just written down `reduce(vcat, reduce.(hcat, reduce(vcat, a)))` to get this as a matrix :). Not the simplest way to do it (and agreed that usually you do not need it), but I found it an interesting exercise of using `hcat`/`vcat`, `reduce` and broadcasting.

Comment: To be honest I battled with it and didn't manage to get the Matrix easily :-)

Comment: You can even drop the first `vcat` you have done and just write `reduce(vcat, reduce.(hcat, a))`.

Comment: I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. The order doesn't matter to me!